# Android DownloadManager Cancel Button

Tags: android, button, android-download-manager

I've implemented a `AsyncTask` to download .pdf files to the storage. I was able to create a custom notification and I added a button to cancel that download.

However, now I have to use **Android's own DownloadManager** to handle the job. When  I start download, it creates a notification showing the progress but I couldn't customize the notification to add a cancel button and run `remove(long)` for it's `onClick()`

Since Google's apps uses downloadManager to download stuff and it has a button to cancel the download, there must be way to achieve.

Comment: make your own dialog with a cancel button !

Comment: that way i cannot send the progress to dialog/notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android N added the cancel option on notification when using Download Manager. There are some posts about it: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029895/android-n-download-manager-notification-cancel-button), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231544/downloadmanager-and-android-7-0-cancel-feature).