# DownloadManager and Android 7.0 Cancel feature

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-7.0-nougat

Android N brought the **"cancel"** feature directly on the download notification if you're using the ***DownloadManager***.

Did they add any intent-filter action to catch this event ?

At this point DownloadManager gets only 3 actions :

- **ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE**
- **ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED**
- **ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS**

I tried to use `ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED` to cancel manually my download but if the user clicks on the **"Cancel"** button, I'm not notified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DownloadManager should send `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` broadcast to your app if user click on Cancel. But it is a known bug in Android N, Android team is working on it:

[Issue 219785:  DownloadManager dose't send ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE broadcast while click CANCEL button on notification to cancel the downloading.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219785)

We have to wait for fix!